# Leaflet Mapa donde poder calcular lo metros cuadrados. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapa

mi problema es que necesito poner en una web un mapa donde me permita seleccionar una parte y que me indique lo metros cuadrados.

He visto que con la api de google se puede pero es de pago.

Estoy intentando usar leaflet y he visto que tiene pluging como el draw que se supone deja hacer formas y otro que se llama measure o algo asi que te dice los metros cuadrados de zonas seleccionadas pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar mas alla del mapa normal de leaflet.

Comment: Publica el código de lo que has intentado, para saber donde puede estar el problema.

Comment: En realidad no tengo mucho hecho. Simplemente el codigo para que aparezca el mapa. He probado a poner estos plugins segun la web oficial pero no me aclaro. Si alguien me puede ayudar a poner esos 2 plugins se lo agradecería.

Comment: Parece que [leaflet.measure](https://github.com/ljagis/leaflet-measure) hace lo que necesitas, inténtalo y, si algo falla, edita la pregunta para agregar el código y explicar qué es lo que no funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Es cierto con [Leaflet Draw](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html) se puede crear un herramienta que mida el área de un polígono dibujado. Aqui va un ejemplo de código para dicha herramienta. Copialo y pruébalo en tu mapa.

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

<script>
    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [19.01, -71.22],
        zoom: 8,
    });
    const tileURL = 'https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    L.tileLayer(tileURL).addTo(map);

    var geometriasDibujadas = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
    var controlDibujo = new L.Control.Draw ({
        edit: {
            featureGroup: geometriasDibujadas,
            edit: false,
        },
        draw: {
            polygon: true,
            rectangle: false,
            circle: false,
            circlemarker: false,
            polyline: false,
            marker: false,
        }
    });
    map.addControl(controlDibujo);

    var obtenerContenido = function(layer, type) {
        var contenido = null;
        var area = L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea(layer._defaultShape()),
            areaLegible = L.GeometryUtil.readableArea(area, true),
            contenido = areaLegible;
        return contenido;
    };

    map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(e) {
        var layer = e.layer,
            type = e.layerType;
        layer.bindTooltip(obtenerContenido(layer, type), {
            permanent: true,
            direction: 'bottom',
            offset: L.point(0, -10),
        }); 
        geometriasDibujadas.addLayer(layer);
    });

</script>
```

Procura usar estos cdn's para Draw:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw-src.css" integrity="sha512-vJfMKRRm4c4UupyPwGUZI8U651mSzbmmPgR3sdE3LcwBPsdGeARvUM5EcSTg34DK8YIRiIo+oJwNfZPMKEQyug==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.js" integrity="sha512-ozq8xQKq6urvuU6jNgkfqAmT7jKN2XumbrX1JiB3TnF7tI48DPI4Gy1GXKD/V3EExgAs1V+pRO7vwtS1LHg0Gw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Con la herramienta se dibuja un polígono y de forma automática se inserta una etiqueta  con el área en unidades de hectáreas. El valor del área no es exacta (leer documentación)